# On-Board Ethernet not working, but it works with a live session

Tags: 16.04, networking, upgrade, hardware

I upgraded the motherboard in one of my Ubuntu 16.04 LTS servers. The On-board Ethernet is not working. Some utilities work (nslookup dig) others don't (ping, apt), but if I boot a Live session everything works as expected.

I've tried using Network Manager and /etc/network/interfaces with similar results. I think it may have something to do with the way the card is initialized since the live session uses a different method than the normal initramfs.

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
# Onboard Ethernet Chip
auto enp1s0
iface enp1s0 inet static
 address 192.168.1.24
 netmask 255.255.255.0
 gateway 192.168.1.1
 dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4 75.75.75.75 75.75.76.76
#PCI network card
auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static
 address 192.168.1.24
 netmask 255.255.255.0
 gateway 192.168.1.1
 dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4 75.75.75.75 75.75.76.76
```

I can't provide a current `ip a` because the on-board chip is currently disabled and the machine is in use.

```
# ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp1s10: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:e0:4c:23:2f:4f brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.24/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global enp1s10
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 2603:3001:600:4a00:2e0:4cff:fe23:2f4f/64 scope global mngtmpaddr dynamic
       valid_lft 282021sec preferred_lft 282021sec
    inet6 fe80::2e0:4cff:fe23:2f4f/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

`# ifconfig -a`

```
enp1s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 70:85:c2:52:a7:90
          inet addr:192.168.1.24  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::5e0c:24b8:27f4:2e6c/64 Scope:Link
          inet6 addr: 2603:3001:600:4a00::e26d/128 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: 2603:3001:600:4a00:9a35:f87c:b10f:c5a0/64 Scope:Global
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:3536 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1868 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:489507 (489.5 KB)  TX bytes:929238 (929.2 KB)
          Interrupt:18

enp2s10   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:e0:4c:23:2f:4f
          inet addr:192.168.1.125  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: 2603:3001:600:4a00:43af:6646:5ef6:c246/64 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: fe80::7794:bc85:8805:13c7/64 Scope:Link
          inet6 addr: 2603:3001:600:4a00::770/128 Scope:Global
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:958 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:107 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:100336 (100.3 KB)  TX bytes:16421 (16.4 KB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host



root@thelma:/etc# lshw -C network
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8169 PCI Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: a
       bus info: pci@0000:02:0a.0
       logical name: eth1
       version: 10
       serial: 00:e0:4c:23:2f:4f
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 66MHz
       capabilities: pm bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full ip=192.168.1.24 latency=64 link=yes maxlatency=64 mingnt=32 multicast=yes port=MII speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:19 ioport:e800(size=256) memory:effffc00-effffcff memory:effc0000-effdffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: QCA8171 Gigabit Ethernet
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       logical name: enp1s0
       version: 10
       serial: 70:85:c2:52:a7:90
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=alx duplex=full ip=192.168.1.26 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:27 memory:efec0000-efefffff ioport:dc00(size=128)
```

lsmod with the on-board chip disabled

```
# lsmod
Module                  Size  Used by
ipt_REJECT             16384  3
nf_reject_ipv4         16384  1 ipt_REJECT
xt_multiport           16384  1
iptable_filter         16384  1
ip_tables              24576  1 iptable_filter
x_tables               36864  4 ip_tables,xt_multiport,iptable_filter,ipt_REJECT
binfmt_misc            20480  1
nvidia              11407360  40
snd_hda_codec_realtek    90112  1
snd_hda_codec_generic    77824  1 snd_hda_codec_realtek
kvm_amd                65536  0
kvm                   548864  1 kvm_amd
irqbypass              16384  1 kvm
crct10dif_pclmul       16384  0
snd_hda_intel          40960  3
crc32_pclmul           16384  0
snd_hda_codec         135168  3 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_intel
snd_hda_core           77824  4 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel
ghash_clmulni_intel    16384  0
aesni_intel           167936  0
snd_hwdep              16384  1 snd_hda_codec
aes_x86_64             20480  1 aesni_intel
lrw                    16384  1 aesni_intel
gf128mul               16384  1 lrw
snd_pcm               106496  3 snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_core
glue_helper            16384  1 aesni_intel
snd_seq_midi           16384  0
ablk_helper            16384  1 aesni_intel
snd_seq_midi_event     16384  1 snd_seq_midi
cryptd                 20480  3 ghash_clmulni_intel,aesni_intel,ablk_helper
snd_rawmidi            32768  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_seq                69632  2 snd_seq_midi_event,snd_seq_midi
drm                   364544  2 nvidia
i2c_nforce2            16384  0
snd_seq_device         16384  3 snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq_midi
edac_mce_amd           24576  0
snd_timer              32768  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
edac_core              53248  0
k10temp                16384  0
fam15h_power           16384  0
shpchp                 36864  0
snd                    81920  16 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hwdep,snd_timer,snd_pcm,snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_seq_device
soundcore              16384  1 snd
8250_fintek            16384  0
input_leds             16384  0
serio_raw              16384  0
mac_hid                16384  0
nfsd                  319488  1
auth_rpcgss            61440  1 nfsd
nfs_acl                16384  1 nfsd
lockd                  94208  1 nfsd
grace                  16384  2 nfsd,lockd
parport_pc             32768  1
sunrpc                335872  5 nfsd,auth_rpcgss,lockd,nfs_acl
ppdev                  20480  0
lp                     20480  0
parport                49152  3 lp,ppdev,parport_pc
autofs4                40960  3
raid10                 49152  0
raid456               110592  0
async_raid6_recov      20480  1 raid456
async_memcpy           16384  2 raid456,async_raid6_recov
async_pq               16384  2 raid456,async_raid6_recov
async_xor              16384  3 async_pq,raid456,async_raid6_recov
async_tx               16384  5 async_pq,raid456,async_xor,async_memcpy,async_raid6_recov
xor                    24576  1 async_xor
raid6_pq              102400  3 async_pq,raid456,async_raid6_recov
libcrc32c              16384  1 raid456
raid0                  20480  0
multipath              16384  0
linear                 16384  0
raid1                  36864  3
pata_acpi              16384  0
psmouse               131072  0
r8169                  86016  0
sata_nv                32768  6
pata_amd               20480  0
mii                    16384  1 r8169
floppy                 73728  0
fjes                   28672  0
```

Comment: We need more information, post `/etc/network/interfaces` and `ip a`

Comment: Here you go, but I don't think that is the answer.

Comment: I'll hae to figure out how to reply, I'm new here I can't get the formatting right.

Comment: just edit your question if you have addittional information then use this ` to surround your code

Comment: Have you compared the kernel modules (`lsmod`) loaded by live and installed versions?

Comment: I didn't check when I was testing. I'm not currently on site can't be sure the answer today is the same as when the on-board Ethernet was enabled. I did check to verify that  the correct driver for the chip was being loaded (alx)